# What can be done about ember actions that may be fired after the user has transitioned to a new route?

Tags: ember.js

I am having a problem with route-level actions that occur asynchronously occasionally not getting handled.

In my Ember app I sometimes receive the error:

```
Nothing handled the action 'X'. If you did handle the action, this error
can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller,
causing the action to bubble.
```

Where `X` is the name of some action. The problem is not that the action is bubbling or that the handler is not defined, because it works almost all the time.

The problem, rather, relates to to fact the `this.send('X')` is called in a promise callback, e.g., after saving a model:

```
model.save().then(() => {
    this.send('X');
});
```

If the save encounters some network congestion or a delay on my server then the user might have navigated to another route by the time the promise is resolved. And that route might not have an action `X` defined (or worse perhaps it's the wrong action of the same name).

Is using actions here a fundamental design flaw?

If so, this would seem to severely limit the utility of actions, because they couldn't be used in any asynchronous context.

Or is there some way that transitions out of a route can delayed until any pending async stuff is resolved? (though this might create it's own undesirable symptoms)

Comment: It seems that closure actions don't suffer from this problem. They can fire asynchronously even after transitioning out of the route where the controller is active. This isn't exactly a solution because I was asking about route actions, but I have found I can usually redesign things to use closure actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO there is not a design flaw in the case you have described. This is the nature of the promises. The same thing can happen within components and there might occur some errors related with trying to set properties on destroyed Ember components. There is a great addon I use to handle such cases: [Ember Concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs)

If you take a look at this addon; you will see that there are similar cases explained, which are very similar to the one you have described. I would suggest benefiting from a popular, already heavily used library like this one instead of trying to tackle it by your own. My best regards.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplicity of coding, I would suggest to move such actions to `Application Controller` and `inject` it wherever needed.

Application Controller can be injected as

```
import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Controller.extend({  
   appController: Ember.inject.controller('application')
 });
```

To use it in Template:

```
<button {{action 'X' target=appController}}> Login </button>
```

To invoke it from your code

`this.get('appController').send('X');`

You can also use [Service to achieve this](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isDestroyed](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#property_isDestroyed) guard check before calling `send`. But I would encourage you to use [ember-concurrency addon](https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency) for this use case. If you can go through [How to do you check for `isDestroyed`?](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-do-you-check-for-isdestroyed/9621) discussion forum, you will get the idea.